# Text Align Left and Right and Vertically Centered in Fixed Header

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I want to align align text Left and Right and center vertically in a Fixed Header. Right now it's currently centered. But it's centered by `line height`, I am not sure if that's the proper way of doing it.

**Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/bassmu1x/1/**

```
    <body>
<div class="header">
    <ul class="links">
        <li>Archive</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>?</li>
        <li>Submit</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="home">home</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

```
.header {
background: #f5f5f5;
width: 100%;
display: block;
position: fixed;
height: 75px;
} 

ul li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
float: right;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-right: 3px;
line-height: 35px;
}

.home {
float: left;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-right: 3px;
line-height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/NfeVh/4/

Comment: Do you care what order your HTML elements are in? Can the home element appear before the ul element in the markup?

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin top if you like   http://jsfiddle.net/bassmu1x/5/

```
ul li {
margin-top:10px;
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
float: right;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-right: 3px;
}
.home {
float: left;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-top:10px;
padding-right: 3px;
margin-top
}
```

Comment: how did you get 10px for `margin-top`

Answer (score 0):

Dude

Use this Way http://jsfiddle.net/bassmu1x/6/

HTML

```
 <ul class="links">
            <li class="home">Home</li>
            <li>Archive</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>?</li>
            <li>Submit</li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    height: 75px;
}
ul{margin:0;padding:0; margin-top:24px}
ul li {
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-right: 3px;
}
.home {
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    padding-right: 3px;
    margin-top
}
```

Comment: Why is `margin-top: 24px;` instead of 35px; ? I understand that If i do 35 px, it will not be centered even though the height is 75px.